# angularjs possibly unhandled rejection could not find map

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-map

I start by saying that I already saw all the similar questions. I have an `angularjs` application which uses `ng-map` and `ui-router`. The problem is the one mentioned in the title. When this error is thrown the map ends up in the middle of the ocean.

I read that this could be a problem of `ng-map` so I raised the value of the timeout, but didn't solve the problem. I also read that could be a problem between `ui-router` and `ng-map`, but I don't know what to do about it. The real problem is that happens randomly, so I can not reproduce it. If I do hard refresh of the page after the problem occurs (the map goes in the middle of the ocean) the application work just fine.

There is anybody that has an idea of how I could solve this problem? A solution would be to reload the page from javascript when the error occurs, the problem is that I didn't find a way of intercepting this error, so that I can refresh the page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some promise is throwing an error. Add a catch block and maybe that error will tell you more

```
getMapOrSomething() <-- Promise
.then(function (response) {})
.catch(function (error) {
  // debug error
});
```

Comment: I still not understood what is causing the problem, but for now I fix it by intercepting the error an doing a reload of the page, so that all the angularjs variables are reinitialized (and it works fine). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I actually was not able to get the error (the thing is that this behavior happens only on a virtual platform, which I can't access, and also it is happening very rarely). The testing is done by another team. They said that in the console log no error message appeared, even if in the catch I did the console log. I know it is a messed up situation, I'm sorry that I don't have more informations.